# Configuring Nutch 2.3 with HSQL 2.3.3 - ClassNotFoundException : org/apache/avro/ipc/ByteBufferOutputStream

Tags: hsqldb, nutch, avro, gora

I'm getting ClassNotFoundException : org/apache/avro/ipc/ByteBufferOutputStream when I run apache Nutch with HSQLDB although I have all the avro related jar files under lib

```
    avro-1.7.6.jar
    avro-compiler-1.7.6.jar
    avro-ipc-1.7.6.jar
    avro-mapred-1.7.6.jar
```

This is what I did:

1. Got HSQLDB up and running

   ```
   root@elephant hsqldb#  sudo java -cp /home/hsqldb/hsqldb-2.3.3/hsqldb/lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server --props /home/hsqldb/hsqldb-2.3.3/hsqldb/conf/server.properties
   [Server@372f7a8d]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) entered
   [Server@372f7a8d]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) exited
   [Server@372f7a8d]: Startup sequence initiated from main() method
   [Server@372f7a8d]: Loaded properties from [/home/hsqldb/hsqldb-2.3.3/hsqldb/conf/server.properties]
   [Server@372f7a8d]: Initiating startup sequence...
   [Server@372f7a8d]: Server socket opened successfully in 28 ms.
   [Server@372f7a8d]: Database [index=0, id=0, db=file:/home/hsqldb/hsqldb-2.3.3/hsqldb/data/nutch, alias=nutchdb] opened sucessfully in 1406 ms.
   [Server@372f7a8d]: Startup sequence completed in 1438 ms.
   [Server@372f7a8d]: 2015-12-26 18:30:13.841 HSQLDB server 2.3.3 is online on port 9001
   [Server@372f7a8d]: To close normally, connect and execute SHUTDOWN SQL
   [Server@372f7a8d]: From command line, use [Ctrl]+[C] to abort abruptly
   ```
2. Configured  ivy/ivy.xml

uncommented below lines in ivy.xml

```
 <dependency org="org.apache.gora" name="gora-core" rev="0.5" conf="*->default"/>
```

and

```
<dependency org="org.apache.gora" name="gora-sql" rev="0.1.1-incubating"
   conf="*->default" />
```

uncommented the below lines conf/gora.properites

```
###############################
# Default SqlStore properties #
###############################

gora.sqlstore.jdbc.driver=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
gora.sqlstore.jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/nutchdb
gora.sqlstore.jdbc.user=sa
gora.sqlstore.jdbc.password=
```

3. Ran ant build

   ```
   ant runtime
   ```
4. Added configuration for nutch-site.xml

   ```
   root@elephant conf# cat nutch-site.xml
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

   <!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

   <configuration>

           <property>
                   <name>storage.data.store.class</name>
                   <value>org.apache.gora.sql.store.SqlStore</value>
           </property>

           <property>
                   <name>http.agent.name</name>
                   <value>NutchCrawler</value>
           </property>

           <property>
                   <name>http.robots.agents</name>
                   <value>NutchCrawler,*</value>
           </property>

   </configuration>
   ```
5. Created seed.txt under urls folder
6. Executed the nutch by injecting the urls

   ```
   [root@elephant local]# bin/nutch inject urls/
   InjectorJob: starting at 2015-12-26 19:11:24
   InjectorJob: Injecting urlDir: urls
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/avro/ipc/ByteBufferOutputStream
   at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:259)
   at org.apache.nutch.storage.StorageUtils.getDataStoreClass(StorageUtils.java:93)
   at org.apache.nutch.storage.StorageUtils.createWebStore(StorageUtils.java:77)
   at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:218)
   at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.inject(InjectorJob.java:252)
   at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:275)
   at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
   at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.main(InjectorJob.java:284)
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.avro.ipc.ByteBufferOutputStream
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
   ... 9 more
   ```

Comment: I ask you to flag the answer as correct :) thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gora-sql is not supported. Due some licenses issues (if I am not wrong), it became disabled around Gora 0.2.

So I suggest you to use other storage like, for example, HBase.

How to get HBase up&running fast: read answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39837926/582789